# Issues deleting a flow version

Tags: visual-workflow, metadata-api, workbench, destructivechanges.xml

I am having an issue with the deletion of a flow version. Using standard declarative ways the version will not delete and removing the flow all together gives an internal service error so I have been attempting to delete it via the workbench. However I keep getting an error **"Problem: setup object in use"** I cant seem to find a resolution I have attempted to; deactivate it / remove from all lightning pages but i cant find out where its still in use at.

does anyone know what this error specifically refers to?
below is my destructiveChanges.xml info

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Client_Updates_v_2-11</members>
        <name>Flow</name> 
    </types>
</Package>
```

Comment: Do you have any Paused Interviews or Scheduled Actions on the Flow?

Comment: Nope just looked, there are no paused flow interviews or scheduled actions.

Comment: Did you figure it out?  I'm having a similar problem.  Can't delete flow or flow-versions.  It's like nothing even tries.

Answer (score 1):

Try to deactivate all the versions and start deleting with the oldest version of the flow and flow interviews that are linked with it.